# Vectorizing name replacement over range of columns

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a large dataset so this is a toy example.

Here is the dataframe `df`

```
structure(list(Target = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Jim", 
"Kurt", "Lester", "Tara", "Taylor"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), Partner1 = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Andrew", "Jim", "Mickey", "Taylor"
), class = "factor"), Partner2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("Andrew", "Jim", "Kurt", "Mickey"), class = "factor"), 
    Partner4 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Andrew", 
    "Jim", "Lester", "Tara"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I want to de-identify every member of the Target and Partner columns using the key provided here.

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Andrew", 
"Jim", "Kurt", "Lester", "Mickey", "Taylor"), class = "factor"), 
    id = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A3", 
    "J9", "K5", "L4", "M4", "T7"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I know that you can replace the names of each column individually in this way

```
df[["Partner1"]] <- key[ match(df[['Partner1']], key[['name']] ) , 'id']
```

but I'd like to vectorize it so that I can re-code every name inside the key to it's corresponding id across all columns in parallel

The real data will be hundreds of columns and about 30 of those columns will be the ones I want to de-identify

Any suggestions?

Comment: So something like `cbind({columns I want})` then run lapply over everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another base `R` solution:

```
# Create lookup vector
lu_vect <- setNames(as.character(df2[["id"]]), df2[["name"]])
lu_vect
#   Jim Mickey Andrew Taylor Lester   Kurt 
#  "J9"   "M4"   "A3"   "T7"   "L4"   "K5"

# Make a list of columns we want to *update*
cols_to_anonymise <- c("Target", "Partner1", "Partner2", "Partner4")

# Anonymise column by column, if name is not in key, replace by NA
df[cols_to_anonymise] <- lapply(
  df[cols_to_anonymise],
  function(x) lu_vect[as.character(x)]
)

# Print out results
df
#   Target Gender Partner1 Partner2 Partner4
# 1     J9      M       A3       J9     <NA>
# 2   <NA>      F       T7       K5       L4
# 3     T7      F       T7       A3       J9
# 4     K5      M       J9       M4       L4
# 5     L4      M       M4       K5       A3
```

Comment: Looks and works great! in the cols_to_anonymise part can I select just a range of column names like c("Target", "Partner1:Partner4")? I'm guessing it wouldn't look like that, but I'm curious because the full example has a lot of columns to select from and I'd rather index from the first and last column.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are doing the `as.character` function here? Just curious

Comment: Selecting the columns. Maybe `startsWith()` or `grep()` can help you? factor variables look similar but are actually very different from character variables.

Answer (score 3):

A possibile solution in base R :

```r
# column names to replace
cols <- c('Target','Partner1','Partner2','Partner4')
# convert df subset to a matrix of characters
mx <- as.matrix(df[,cols])
# get the replacements values using match
repl <- as.character(key$id)[match(mx,as.character(key$name))]
# substitute NA's in replacements with the original values
repl[is.na(repl)] <- mx[is.na(repl)]
# create a copy of df
df2 <- df
# replace the values of df2 with the replacements
df2[,cols] <- repl
```

Result :

```r
> df2
  Target Gender Partner1 Partner2 Partner4
1     J9      M       A3       J9     Tara
2   Tara      F       T7       K5       L4
3     T7      F       T7       A3       J9
4     K5      M       J9       M4       L4
5     L4      M       M4       K5       A3
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 left_join(df2, by = c("val" = "name")) %>%
 mutate(val = ifelse(var == "Gender", val, 
                     ifelse(!is.na(id), paste0(id), NA_character_))) %>%
 select(-id) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Gender Partner1 Partner2 Partner4 Target
1      M       A3       J9     <NA>     J9
2      F       T7       K5       L4   <NA>
3      F       T7       A3       J9     T7
4      M       J9       M4       L4     K5
5      M       M4       K5       A3     L4
```

First, it performs a wide-long data transformation. Second, it joins the transformed df with df2. If there is an ID in df2 for the name in df, it replaces the name in df with that ID, otherwise with NA. Finally, it transforms the data back to the original format.

Or a base R solution:

```
data.frame(apply(df[, -2], 2, function(x) as.character(df2$id)[match(x, as.character(df2$name))]),
           Gender = df[, 2])

  Target Partner1 Partner2 Partner4 Gender
1     J9       A3       J9     <NA>      M
2   <NA>       T7       K5       L4      F
3     T7       T7       A3       J9      F
4     K5       J9       M4       L4      M
5     L4       M4       K5       A3      M
```

Comment: For base R, is there a way to make the other columns immutable so I don't have to re-attach the Gender columns that don't get de-identified? My real example has many hundreds of columns I want to keep and would rather not select each one in the `data.frame` function